# javascript THIS versus angular $SCOPE.$ON

Tags: angularjs, virtual-machine, this

I've been working with angular 1.x for 2 years or so. I usually follow a recipe not to get into trouble frequently. recently I started trying new approaches in order to better understand angular and javascript.

I used to believe the "vm" thing I was declaring in the javascript controller was the link (bind) to the data-ng-controller="mycontroller as vm" declared in the html. I've just learned I can name them differently and the bind will still happen perfectly.

Then, I decided to stop declaring the "vm" thing in the controller and start using the native javascript "this" qualifier.

I tried the following:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('Customers', [function() {
 //   var vm = this;
      this.title = 'Customers';
      this.customers = [
        {name: 'Haley'}, {name: 'Ella'}, {name: 'Landon'}, {name: 'John'}
        ];


    function 1stFunction () {
        this.obj1 = {}; 
    ;



    function 2ndFunction () {
        this.var2 = {};     
    ;


    $scope.$on('myListener', function() {
        this.var3 = {};
    });

    }]);
```

to my surprise, when I run the application I get a "this is not defined"  message (or something close to this) referring to the **this.var3 = {}** inside  **$scope.$on**. Just the attribution inside **$scope.$on**. Every other attributions inside the functions will work.

If I just replace "this"" for "vm" all over the controller, things will work perfectly again.

I was wondering if someone could explain what exactly is going on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The anonymous function you pass to $scope.$on() is just a regular function. It's not bound to `this`. You would need to use

```
 $scope.$on('myListener', function() {
    this.var3 = {};
 }.bind(this));
```

or to use an ES6 arrow function which does that automatically (if your browser supports ES6, or if you transpile your code from ES6 to ES5):

```
$scope.$on('myListener', () => {
  this.var3 = {};
});
```

Or, as you've done until now, capture the value of `this` in a local variable that is captured by all the functions:

```
var vm = this;

// no risk of not binding this anymore
$scope.$on('myListener', function() {
    vm.var3 = {};
});
```

Frankly, if you're not ready to use ES6 yet, I would keep using the `vm` alias trick (or to use $scope, which doesn't have this problem).

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. I tried the ".bind(this)" on "scope.on" and it worked. however, now I'm getting the same error in the functions. I created a variable inside "scope.on" and tried to use it in another function, but now I get "vm is undefined" within the function. I thought THIS would be the qualifier for global variables and that any variable qualified by it would be visible throughout the entire javascript source code.